# getting error when createing read replica in aws rds

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

When I am trying to create the replica on AWS we are getting the following error

FATAL: could not connect to the primary server: connection to server at 10.3.2.172, port 5432 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user rdsrepladmin.

I am reying to creating a new replica in AWS RDS rds instance. but its showing errors